# Does Leaks Instrument find all leaks?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a game running on the iPad that I'm trying to get running smoothly, and my problem is this, when the user starts it up it is just fine, and even if they play for about 15-20 minutes in one specific game. However if the user goes longer, not sure exactly how long, the game begins to lag, so to speak.

I have run it through the leaks instrument and at first I had a ton of leaks, but now I have it down to just 2, a NSMutableArray and a NSString. But these are only created once and it says that they are only occupying 32 bytes each.

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: the 'lag' may not be due to memory leaks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then it's probably not a leak :)

You might have a situation where you're using more and more memory but it's not leaking because you still have a reference to it somewhere (for example adding data to an array; the array gets bigger and bigger but it's not leak - instruments can't tell what you plan to do with it!)

It's also probably not directly a memory issue - for example if you are continually adding something to an array the array will get bigger and bigger but that might not be your problem. You problem might be that each frame you iterate through the array, this will take longer and longer as the array gets bigger and bigger.

Can you think of anywhere is your game where this king of thing might be happening?

You could also use instruments to look a your memory usage over time and see if it goes up and up or if it stays level.

Answer (score 2):

As @deanWombourne mentioned, it might not be a leak. It might be so-called abandoned memory.
Look at Instruments Memory Allocations and see if the Live Bytes column on the All Allocations line continues to increase over time. You can take Heapshots while repeating a certain sequence of operations in the game. See the following for a description of how to take Heapshots:

http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/